# Debugging Nim source filter

Tags: templates, nim-lang

Can someone point out what's syntactically wrong with this source filter (as documented here - https://nim-lang.org/docs/filters.html) as it refuses to compile with an "invalid indentation" error message

```
#? stdtmpl | standard
#proc greet(name = "world"): string =
# result = ""
<h1>Hello $name</h1>
#end proc

echo greet()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `echo greet()` is Nim code, you need to prefix it with `#`. Also, be aware that you may not have empty lines outside the proc, because Nim would then try to append them to a `result` variable, which does not exist outside the proc.

```
#? stdtmpl | standard
#proc greet(name = "world"): string =
# result = ""
<h1>Hello $name</h1>
#end proc
#echo greet()
```

Comment: thanks flyx! wish the documentation stated this clearly (especially the part about empty lines) and the fact that these templates need to be in their own files!